# how to load edit and save word document from windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-forms-designer

I want to open a word document in windows forms with the option to edit and save. 
I have tried using web browser control but it opens a word document as a separate application.
How can i load the document within the web browser control or is there any other choice to achieve this?
I want to achieve this using visual studio 2008 or 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a Word Document within a Web Browser control, unless you are navigating to a URL which is an Office 365, Sharepoint Online or Sharepoint site which implement Office Web Apps.

Comment: thanq @PhillipH. Is there any other work around to achieve this? Tried using winwordcontrol.dll but it threw TypeInitializationException. Pls help.

Comment: No. Not that I know of. A browser is for browsing HTML + JavaScript. A Word document isnt either of those things, so your browser will launch an external application to deal with the data stream it cannot render.